# How to change data(string) from a txt file so I can do mathematical operations on that data?

Tags: java, arrays, file, bufferedreader

For my question I saw an reminder that many have already asked this question, but I cant seem to find a decent answer. Or answers are in other programing languages which doesnt help me. So I will ask again :)

I have to read from a txt file, then do some mathematical operations on the data. This data is in 10000 lines and in each line is 20 numbers separated by a semicolon. 
For reading from txt file I used BufferedReader which gives me string. I probably have to change this string to int. So far so good. Then I have to make it into an array...how? Does the array need to be two dimensional or one dimension is enough?

Then in the end I have to write results in different txt files. I have to write to different files numbers that are dividable by 3, 11 and 5, then I have to sum each row in txt file and make the sum of whole txt numbers.
Is what I wrote until now ok? Should I delete something or?

```
class Assignment {

    public static void main (String[] args) {

        String nameFile = "numbers.txt";
        String contentFile = readFromFile(nameFile);
        List<Integer> divideNumber = stringToIntList(contentFile);

        List<Integer> divisibleNo = processedData(divideNumber);

        System.out.println(divideNumber);
    }

    private static String readFromFile(String nameFile) {
        String content = "";
        try {
            File file = new File(nameFile);
            BufferedReader read = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));

            String line = read.readLine();
            while(line != null) {
                System.out.println(line);
                line = read.readLine();
                content = line;
            }
            read.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("There was an error reading from the file");
        }
        return content;
    }

    private static List<Integer> stringToIntList(String contentFile) {
        return Arrays
            .stream(contentFile.split("; "))
            .map(Integer::parseInt)
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }

    private static int processedData(int divideNumber) {
        try {
            for(int i = 0; i < divideNumber; i++) {
                if((divideNumber % 3 == 0) || (divideNumber % 5 == 0) || (divideNumber % 11 == 0)) {
                System.out.println(divideNumber);
                }
            }
        }
        catch(NumberFormatException e){
            System.out.println("It is not a number"); 
        }
        return divideNumber;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a Scanner with appropriate delimiter:

```
List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new FileInputStream(nameFile))
   .useDelimiter("\\D+");
while (scanner.hasNext()) {
    int i = scanner.nextInt();
    list.add(i);
}
```

Comment: I have to ask. Why not BufferedReader? And what means .useDelimiter("\\D+")? Also,  when I want to do the operations later, I will be able to use this "list"?

Comment: @Escape There is nothing in `BufferedReader` that converts strings to integers. You can do this yourself, although you don't appear to know how. `Scanner` encapsulates it. You could always look up `useDelimiter()` for yourself. It's documented.

Comment: @user207421 I think that I can parse data that was read with BufferedReader, or am I wrong? But I dont know how to do operations on this data later.

Comment: @Escape How do I know what you can and can't do? There is no evidence of knowing how to convert strings to integers in your question, and the last part of your comment is merely vague.

Comment: I guess I will use scanner. But I wanted to learn it with BufferedReader. @user207421 comments and chat is here to clarify what is missing or misunderstood in question or future conversation and help each other, not point fingers :) I am just looking to learn and get some help. I see you have a lot of knowledge. Can you help me finish this assignment?